# “No-brainer” as a noun in French

Tags: traduction, anglais, demande-de-mot, noms

There are several ways of translating into French the idea conveyed by *“no-brainer”*, as in:

> It seems like **a no-brainer** to improve standards.
>
> - Améliorer les standards ? **Ça va de soi** *or* **Poser la question, c’est y répondre**.
> - Ça semble **une évidence** que l’on doive monter la barre.
> - **Ce n’est que normal** que l’on fasse progresser les normes.

While the second translation I propose does transform the noun into a noun, *“évidence”* is not always the most appropriate translation:

> “How should I approach this stability problem?”
>   “That's **a no brainer**, use a dovetail.”
>
> « Comment devrais-je assurer la stabilité du montage ?
>
> - **Ne te pose pas de questions**, utilise une queue d’aronde !
> - **Le mieux, et de loin,** sera une queue d’aronde.

I feel the use of *“évidence”* in this case would be too condescending, because *“évidence”* has more of an absolute value than *“no brainer”*, the latter allowing for person-specific experience and knowledge.

Would there be, then, beside *“évidence”*, another noun that could cover in a gentler manner the idea of *“no brainer”?*

Comment: I'd use "Pas besoin d'être un génie pour ...".

Comment: @Alone-zee That wouldn't be very gentle, would it? :S

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd find «c'est facile» just as condescending as «évident», and the latter a reasonable translation for “no-brainer”.

That said, a couple or three other suggestions:

- Start with **évidemment**, because it draws the listener in and says “you’ve already realised that ...” rather than “it should be obvious that ...”
- A bit of searching led me to «**Ça coule de source**» and «**Ce n'est pas compliqué**».  The former is quite a figurative phrase, which compliments the listener; the latter is *un peu dur*).
- Obviously if you wish to avoid condescension, avoid beginning with «**Franchement, je crois que la question ne doit pas se poser...**» :o)

Comment: A few more suggestions can be found [here on a site called _Linguee_](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/it%27s+a+no+brainer.html)

Comment: You could also say, "ce n'est pas bien sorcier" or "ça ne casse pas trois pattes à un canard", in a more familiar way.

Answer (score 3):

If your desire to express this concept with a noun would be satisfied by declaring the **absence** of an antonym/near antonym of that noun, maybe you could consider using that strategy, perhaps as follows:

Granted,  there’s technically a gap in meaning between “**not** being something [e.g., a brain-teaser/twister] and actually “**being** the near opposite of that thing [[e.g., a no-brainer](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/1995/09/05/brain-teaser-or-no-brainer-take-this-test-and-find-out-fast/ac4b0d56-9073-4629-b46e-3d63816847fd/)], but it’s possible that the nuance caused by this very gap could actually present an opportunity to soften a bit the notion of “It’s a no-brainer” by replacing it with “It’s not a brain teaser,” ...
... first in English (for I, in spite of your observation, often hear/see “no-brainer” used condescendingly in that language, too) ...
... and then in French to slightly temper the condescending tone of ...
 ... “C’est/Ça semble une evidence que …” with, for example:

> [Ce n'est pas un mystère {que
>   …}](https://books.google.com/books?id=pc0qAQAAMAAJ&q=%22ce+n%27est+pas+un+myst%C3%A8re%22&dq=%22ce+n%27est+pas+un+myst%C3%A8re%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSo6LCgY_YAhXH7yYKHet5D9EQ6AEISDAE).

(usage example, possibly relevant, from *Journal des débats*, Volume 28, Issues 41-65 L'Assemblée, 1985 - Québec (Province), via *GoogleBooks*).

---

If, however, the nuance/gap between something “**not being** *un mystère*” and its “**being** *une evidence*” is either too great (i.e., "sorry, but that’s just not what it means") or ...
 ... too slight (i.e., "sorry, but it’s still too condescending"), ...
... then perhaps you could consider a literal translation of “It’s not a brain-teaser/twister,” such as:

> [C{e n}’est pas un casse-tête [chinois].](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/pas+un+casse-t%C3%AAte)

(from *Reverso-Context*).
(but please note that this, too, might be seen as failing to help you reach your admirable goal of avoiding all traces of condescension [and some might even see it as being worse than the original in that respect])

(see also Cath S’s suggestion on [this *Word Reference* thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-no-brainer.1203908/) on “a no-brainer”)

Comment: This is interesting. Since *“no-brainer”* has a self-contained negation, it wouldn’t be that much of a stretch either to negate a concept in French also. Your answer reminded me of *“it’s not rocket science”*, a bit different but in the same vein. Aussi, comme le disent les Russes en suivant Boulgakov dans *Le Maître et Marguerite: «—Quand devez-vous mourir? [...] —Personne n’en sait rien et ça ne regarde personne [...] —Personne n’en sait rien, ah bien oui! [...] **C’est quand même pas le binôme de Newton!** [...]Il mourra dans neuf mois, l’an prochain en février, [...]»*

Comment: Also, I just wanted to point out that I am aware of the condescending use of *“no-brainer”* in English. I just think it **also** allows for a more generic use, which is harder to get across using the French *“évidence”*, because like I said, it conveys more of an absolute value. The wood-worker who would say this is a no-brainer about the usage of dovetails could well think it is a no-brainer for him, since he knows his stuff and there is clearly no better options, and knowing at the same time not everybody has this specific type of knowledge.

Comment: @Feelew I do agree that "C'est une “évidence” (without being expressly qualified with "pour moi/lui" or even with "semble" as in your example) conveys more of an absolute value [even to the point of (trying to) end further discussion (like a "fait indiscutable"?)] than "no-brainer" by itself does (maybe because “évidence” is more serious and/or well-established than "no-brainer," which is fairly recent, I think & somewhat "cutesy"?). On the *WordReference* thread I cited, "Docbike" (from the [arguably stodgy?] UK) argued that "no-brainer" was "so offensive," but s/he was pretty much shot down.

Comment: @Feelew Re "It's not rocket science/brain surgery," I'm not sure, but that might be approaching the notion of "absolute value" conveyed by "C'est une évidence,” where "rocket science" could be seen as setting the absolute apex of what's difficult to grasp or to do, leaving little ground to argue that the speaker was just talking in relative (context-specific/eg "wood-working") terms. (I'm probably shooting my "ce n'est pas un casse-tete" in the foot with that, but then again a generic "casse-tete" wouldn't (necessarily) set the bar quite as high as "rocket science/le binôme de Newton" would.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best would simply be to use the concept of "simplicité" or "facilité".

> Comment devrais-je assurer la stabilité du montage ?
>
> - **C'est simple**, utilise une queue d'aronde !
> - **C'est facile**, utilise une queue d'aronde !

Comment: *C'est tout simple*

Comment: C'est bidon. C'est trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Une proposition de néologisme aux allures de calque morphologique pourrait-on dire mais entièrement français vu qu'elle représente la substantivation de la [locution adverbiale](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/effort) *sans effort* (facilement) :

> *Un sans-effort* [ [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/no-brainer) fr. *no-brainer*,
>   [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=no%20brainer&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) dans un contexte spécialisé (l'entente) ]

Une [*formalité*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/formalit%C3%A9) d'une certaine manière, l'*acte sans difficulté* (TLFi A 2 b). Plus généralement on préfère *ça va de soi* et la *facilité* selon le contexte, tel que mentionné ailleurs... mais c'est un nom !

Comment: Ce sont là deux très belles trouvailles! Un sans-effort saisit exactement la nuance, quoiqu'il ne soit pour l'instant qu'une proposition dont la valeur est pour ainsi dire toute en potentiel. Une formalité *(particulièrement lorsque qualifiée de* simple, *comme c'est souvent le cas)* possède par ailleurs aussi cette ambivalence qui peut servir à exprimer, selon le contexte et l'intonation, autant la simplicité qu'une légère condescendance. Merci de votre réponse!

Comment: @Feelew Je vous en prie. Merci !

Comment: +1 pour une formalité

Comment: Je ne pense pas que ce terme puisse être compris dans le langage courant.